# I need help with an existing variable of drupal

Tags: 7

How I can use in my code the value where exists on configuration->Logging and errors->Database log messages to keep?? Could anyone help me to find out how I can use this number that the user will select? What is the name of these variable??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Database log messages to keep" tells the site how many entries to store in "Recent Log Messages" (/admin/reports/dblog). It stores a record of watchdog events and php warning/errors, etc.

The limit is stored in the variable table, under the variable name of dblog_row_limit.

Comment: $number = variable_get('dblog_row_limit') could I call it something like this? Is this the correct way?

Comment: or something like this? $number_to_keep = db_select('variable', 'va')
    ->fields('value')
    ->condition('name', 'dblog_row_limit', '=')
    ->execute();

Comment: Use variable_get(), drupal loads all the variables in the variable table into the persistent $conf var. So there's no need to hit the db again and you can simply just look up the value from conf with variable_get()